# How to insert save to favourites feature link within modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am using the NASA API which displays images, and when the image is clicked, it displays a modal with the images and details of the image.

However, in the tutorial, there is a save to favourites feature that adds the image and details to the favourites section into local storage.

My question is, how do I implement the add to favourites feature link into the modals, and then save the image and details to the local storage favourites section?

```js
const resultsNav = document.getElementById("resultsNav");
const favoritesNav = document.getElementById("favoritesNav");
const imagesContainer = document.querySelector(".images-container");
const saveConfirmed = document.querySelector(".save-confirmed");
const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");

// NASA API
const count = 3;
const apiKey = 'DEMO_KEY';
const apiUrl = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}&count=${count}`;

let resultsArray = [];
let favorites = {};

// Show Content
function showContent(page) {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "instant"
  });
  if (page === "results") {
    resultsNav.classList.remove("hidden");
    favoritesNav.classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    resultsNav.classList.add("hidden");
    favoritesNav.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
  loader.classList.add("hidden");
}

// Create DOM Nodes
function createDOMNodes(page) {
  const currentArray =
    page === "results" ? resultsArray : Object.values(favorites);
  currentArray.forEach((result) => {
    // Card Container
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");




    // Link that wraps the image
    const link = document.createElement("a");


    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";



      modalImg.src = event.target.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = event.target.alt;

    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }


    // Image
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = result.url;
    // image.alt = "NASA Picture of the Day";
    image.alt = result.title + "<br>" + result.explanation + "<br>" + ' ' + result.date;
    image.loading = "lazy";
    image.classList.add("card-img-top");


    // Card Body
    const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.classList.add("card-body");

    // Card Title
    const cardTitle = document.createElement("h5");
    cardTitle.classList.add("card-title");
    cardTitle.textContent = result.title;

    // Save Text
    const saveText = document.createElement("p");
    saveText.classList.add("clickable");
    if (page === "results") {
      saveText.textContent = "Add To Favorites";
      saveText.setAttribute("onclick", `saveFavorite('${result.url}')`);
    } else {
      saveText.textContent = "Remove Favorite";
      saveText.setAttribute("onclick", `removeFavorite('${result.url}')`);
    }

    // Card Text
    const cardText = document.createElement("p");
    cardText.textContent = result.explanation;

    // Footer Conatiner
    const footer = document.createElement("small");
    footer.classList.add("text-muted");

    // Date
    const date = document.createElement("strong");
    date.textContent = result.date;

    // Copyright
    const copyrightResult =
      result.copyright === undefined ? "" : result.copyright;
    const copyright = document.createElement("span");
    copyright.textContent = ` ${copyrightResult}`;

    // Append everything together
    footer.append(date, copyright);
    cardBody.append(cardTitle, saveText, cardText, footer);
    link.appendChild(image);
    card.append(link); // hide cardBody

    // Append to image container
    imagesContainer.appendChild(card);
  });
}

// Update the DOM
function updateDOM(page) {
  // Get favorites from local storage
  if (localStorage.getItem("nasaFavorites")) {
    favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("nasaFavorites"));
  }
  imagesContainer.textContent = "";
  createDOMNodes(page);
  showContent(page);
}

// Get 10 images from NASA API
async function getNasaPictures() {
  // Show Loader
  loader.classList.remove("hidden");
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    resultsArray = await response.json();
    updateDOM("results");
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch Error Here
  }
}

// Add result to favorites
function saveFavorite(itemUrl) {
  // Loop through the results array to select favorite
  resultsArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.url.includes(itemUrl) && !favorites[itemUrl]) {
      favorites[itemUrl] = item;
      // Show save confirmation for 2 seconds
      saveConfirmed.hidden = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        saveConfirmed.hidden = true;
      }, 2000);
      // Set Favorites in Local Storage
      localStorage.setItem("nasaFavorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
    }
  });
}

// Remove item from favorites
function removeFavorite(itemUrl) {
  if (favorites[itemUrl]) {
    delete favorites[itemUrl];
    localStorage.setItem("nasaFavorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
    updateDOM("favorites");
  }
}

// On Load
getNasaPictures();
```

Comment: Try read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question, I check the Nasa.api and i find that the sever will return you an `array` that contain `object`, so a good option is to use an `array` to store all the liked item and it will be easier for you display.

My suggestion for you is to directly store the info that nasa.api give to you to the array and store in `localStorage`. It will be easier for you to display later.

I also created an example for you that use nasa.api that you could use it since I doesn't have your full code and how you get the code/display it, but you could just see the part that how i modify the localStorage

So in the example I created, every time user click on the liked button, it will save to `liked` (array) and save to `localStorage`. Every second time, user click the button , we will delete the item from the `liked` array and update localStorage.

```js
let source;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let link = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=5"
xhr.open('GET', link, true);
xhr.send();
let liked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("likeditem"));

if (liked == null) liked = [];
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    source = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    create()
  }
} //Check if liked is null, if it is, assign empty array value to it.

function create() {
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    console.log(source[i])
    document.body.innerHTML += `
         <img src=${source[i].url}>
         <div >${source[i].title}</div>
         <div >Date: ${source[i].date}</div>
          <div>Copyright: ${source[i].copyright}</div>
          <div>Media_type: ${source[i].media_type}</div>
          <div>Service_version: ${source[i].service_version}</div>
         <div>Explanation: ${source[i].explanation}</div>
          <button onclick='save(${i})'>Save to like</button>
`
    //TO save/remove liked item from local Storage when button clicked
    window.save = function(index) {
      let thisbutton = document.querySelectorAll('button')[index]
      if (thisbutton.textContent == 'Save to like') {
        liked.push(source[index])
        localStorage.setItem('likeditem', JSON.stringify(liked));
        thisbutton.textContent = "Saved"
      } else {
        //Remove it from local storage when user click it every two times
        liked.splice(liked.indexOf(source[index]), 1)
        localStorage.setItem('likeditem', JSON.stringify(liked));
        thisbutton.textContent = 'Save to like'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In term of how to display the element from localStorage, also an example.

We have already saved all the info about the image to `localStorage` before , so we just use the way we display the info from nasa.api.

```js
let liked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("likeditem"));

for (let i in liked){
//Immediately return the for loop if no value stored in loal storage
if(!liked) break;;
        document.body.innerHTML += `
         <img src=${liked[i].url}>
         <div >${liked[i].title}</div>
         <div >Date: ${liked[i].date}</div>
          <div>Copyright: ${liked[i].copyright}</div>
          <div>Media_type: ${liked[i].media_type}</div>
          <div>Service_version: ${liked[i].service_version}</div>
         <div>Explanation: ${liked[i].explanation}</div>
          `
}
```

Update:

Save to localStorage:

[image]

Display from localStorage:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241434/discussion-on-answer-by-james-how-to-insert-save-to-favourites-feature-link-with).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : This is edit to my previous answer. This piece of of code should help you. (NOTE: this code snippet wont work here, try it from your system as localStorage is not supported here.)

```js
let nasaImages = [
    {
        id:1,
        url:"https://example.com/image-url-1"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        url:"https://example.com/image-url-2"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        url:"https://example.com/image-url-3"
    }
];

let favs = [];

//check if key exists in localstorage
if(localStorage.nasaFavs){
    favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.nasaFavs)
}

renderImages();



function renderImages(){
    $("#images").html(nasaImages.map(image => (
            `<div>
                id: ${image.id}
                <img src='${image.url}'>
                ${favBtn(image.id)}
            </div>`
        )
    ).join(""));
}


//render the fav button
function favBtn(id){
    if(favs.includes(id)){
        return `<button onclick="favUnfav(false,${id})">Remove from fav</button>`;
    }
    else{
        return `<button onclick="favUnfav(true,${id})">Add to fav</button>`;
    }
}


function favUnfav(isFav=true, id=null){
    //write your logic to add to fav or remove from fav
    if(isFav){
        favs.push(id);
    }
    else{
        favs = favs.filter(e => e!=id);
    }

    //save in localstorage
    localStorage.nasaFavs = JSON.stringify(favs);

    //re render the DOM
    renderImages()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I want to ask how do I display the "Add to Favourites link"?

Comment: I have edited the answer please check it once in your local system.

Answer (score 0):

As @ba2sik already posted, first get familiar with [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You are already saving the whole `favorites` object into local storage under `nasaFavorites` key.
In order to read it, use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nasaFavorites'))` to deserialize the content every time you want to access it.

Just note that the code above doesn't handle edge cases or errors so you might want to handle it with `try/catch`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I want to ask how do I display the "Add to Favourites link"?