# I can't get the actual number of elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem returning elements from my object array.

I have a slideshow in which an image (photo of the book) and a text (title of the book) must appear.

For the creation of the slideshow I have no problems because I am using querySelectors as shown in the code below.

The problem lies in showing the images with their titles.

In the first part of the code I have an array of objects that gives me the total number of elements present and based on this I create the slideshow (to create the scroll points and the "container" to contain the images) and then subsequently I call the function myFunction with id argument to return the single element (identified by an id).

What I notice is that the urls with the ids are returned to me, but the url with that id is returned multiple times (so it gets copied) and not just once as expected; I should have only 4 url ​​in total (each with the specific id of the element, since only 4 elements). The same happens when I return the array of objects, it does not return 4 but many more.

Referring to url1:

If I click on the arrows of the slideshow I only receive one image, the other images I do not receive.

I have no mistakes.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;


    var outerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books";
    outerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var innerXmlhttp;
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var allbook = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var i = 0, len = allbook.Items.length; i < len; i++) {
          id = allbook.Items[i].id
          showSlides(slideIndex);
          myFunction(id);
        }
      }
    };
    outerXmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    outerXmlhttp.send();

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides fade");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
      if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }

    function myFunction(id) {
      var url1 = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books/" + id;
      innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      innerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          document.getElementById("img").src = "book_img/" + myArr.Item.immagine;
          document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = `<a href="fragmentProva.html?id=${id}">${myArr.Item.titolo}</a>`;
        }
      };
      innerXmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      innerXmlhttp.send();
    }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container" id="slideshow">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="punt" style="text-align:center">
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

Array allbook with error:
[image]

Comment: IDs need to be unique within an HTML document, you are violating that simple rule with the content you are creating in a loop there. `document.getElementById("img")` and `document.getElementById("title")` later on in your `myFunction` will only ever access the first element with the respective ID they find in the document.

Comment: it's unique, it just returns me the same object array multiple times .. so what should i do? how can i change my code?

Comment: "I have no mistakes" isn't something you generally want to proclaim on the internet. It's usually incorrect.

Comment: Please add a relevant excerpt from the JSON you're getting from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Several things I noticed:

1. Doesn't define the `id`
2. As you state, the data structure from api will look like `{"Item":{"marca":"Love","titolo":"You will be missed indefinitely","id":"123456","immagine":"ind.jpg","data":"27/11/2021"}}`, but are trying to loop over all the item inside item which will be incorrect, you should loop over `allbook`.
3. It should be `allbook[i].Items.length` instead of `allbook.Items.length`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
let id;
var outerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books";
outerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var innerXmlhttp;
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var allbook = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var i = 0, len = allbook.length; i < len; i++) {
      id = allbook[i].Items.id
      document.querySelector('.slideshow-container').innerHTML += `
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">${i+1}/${allbook[i].Items.length}</div>
            <img id="img" src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=myFunction(${id});" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text" id="title" onclick="myFunction(${id})"></div>
          </div>`;
      document.querySelector('#punt').innerHTML += `
          <span class="dot" onclick=currentSlide(${i+1})></span>`;
      myFunction(id);
    }
            showSlides(0);
  }
};
outerXmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
outerXmlhttp.send();

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides fade");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

function myFunction(id) {
  var url1 = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books/" + id;
  innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  innerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("img").src = "book_img/" + myArr.Item.immagine;
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = `<a href="fragmentProva.html?id=${id}">${myArr.Item.titolo}</a>`;
    }
  };
  innerXmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
  innerXmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container" id="slideshow">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<br>

<div id="punt" style="text-align:center">
</div>
```

Comment: @a_l_e_x, i think there is nothing wrong with your code and the code looks good, if you know the way how to solve it, go ahead. Maybe you use the wrong data structure? You could check this answer I yesterday posted to help a person who is also using api, I am using the same way you are using, this may give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827644/17743647. A good suggestion for you is to check the data structure that is return.

Comment: Yes, only one thing I would like to understand. But when I call myFunction in querySelector to return me the title and image is it okay to do it that way? Doubt is rising there

Comment: @a_l_e_x, it kindly depends. If the very link return all the things you want, I would not suggest you to do that, since it takes time for broswer to send/receive data and you may suffer the problem of sever return 409 too many request

Comment: What would you recommend to me? it's the first time I've tried to do such a thing

Comment: @a_l_e_x, I have experience of using api for several times and the best suggestions I could give to you is avoid the times of sending request to sever as much as possible:)

Comment: One last thing. I have a little doubt .. Putting showSlides(slideIndex) in the for is not repeated 4 times (length of my array)? I should only have one that manages my slideshow. If I put it out it gives me an error. Is this also correct as I did?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, i think you are , you putting the showSlides inside the for loop, so you call it and it will execute `allbook.length` times

Comment: But I only need one

Comment: @a_l_e_x, if you only need 1, just call it outside and use showSlides(0), since slides always start at the begining

Comment: @a_l_e_x, Got what you mean, just call it outside the for loop:). Also, I have used try to do similar effect to w3school slide one year ago, my personal opinion  is this is too massy, Just change the src for image will work for you:0

Comment: I realized that I put an obsolete url, sorry. I had to create a new one. I have updated my main question with the actual urls. Can you try to verify the code to see what happens? Because I don't get any errors.

Comment: @a_l_e_x, your code does display right info you want, then how to display it just depends on how you want to do, Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that I don't see anything. I'm going crazy about this

Comment: @a_l_e_x, then there are must be something wrong with your Javascript code structure and you have to figure it out by ourself